# Simplification of special quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Considering the quartic

$$p(x) = x^4+bx^3+cx^2+bx+1$$

Is it possible to convert this equation to a quadratic (bi-quadratic) polynomial?

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried. I could not find a simplified answer. And that is why I asked in this forum. One of the roots looks like this: $$-{{\sqrt{-4\,c+b^2+8}}\over{4}}-{{\sqrt{{{b^2-2\,c}\over{2}}+{{b\,
 \left(8-4\,c\right)+b^3}\over{2\,\sqrt{-4\,c+b^2+8}}}-2}}\over{2}}-
 {{b}\over{4}}$$.

Comment: @PauloGonçalves dunno if that root is correct or not but i dont think you'll get a more simplified answer than that for variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what youre looking for but here it goes

$$\begin{align}
x^4+bx^3+cx^2+bx+1&=0\\
x^2+bx+c+{b\over x}+{1\over x^2}&=0\\
\left({x+\frac1x}\right)^2+b\left({x+\frac1x}\right)+c-2&=0\\
\left({x+\frac1x}\right)={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c+8}\over2}\\
x^2+1={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c+8}\over2}x
\end{align}$$

Then apply quadratic again for the roots

Comment: Great. Thank you. I believe this will help me.